# Is it forbidden to use the Internet on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, internet, melacha-creative-work

Is it forbidden to use the Internet during Shabbat? How can you interpret the Melachos to apply to the 21st century? Is there a difference between looking at the internet for purely information purposes for example this website vs. directly communicating with another person? One way I have been trying to look at the question is read-only use of the internet vs. read-write usage. For example, if someone sends me an email during Shabat, I do not reply to it, but I know that it has been received. After the sun sets, *now* I finally reply to the email.

Comment: Are you asking aside from issues of electricity? Or assuming that one held that electricity was mutar on Shabbos would there be any issues specific to surfing the internet?

Comment: Or are you asking about leaving a computer running, much like a television, and simply watching a CPU monitor, a download rate, or a state of the union address?

Comment: There are many issues, not just electricity - which itself is extremely complicated. The issue of writing is also far more complex than others here have made it seem. There very well could be actual Melachah (constructive labor) issues, as well as Issurei DeRabbanan (rabbinic prohibitions). There is a lot of technical expertise needed to answer this question, which isn't being displayed in the answers.

Comment: Obviously, no section of any tractate of the Talmud (not even "the" tractate, whatever that means) discusses the Internet, [which was invented by Al Gore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Gore_and_information_technology#1999_CNN_interview_misquoting) many years after the Talmud was written. Rewording your question to indicate exactly what you mean to ask would help.

Comment: hunterp, the new version of this question contains two distinct questions, each of which is different from your original question. (1: "How can you interpret ..." and 2: "Is there a difference ...") I recommend that you spin each of those off into a new question.

Answer (score 7):

Hunterp, hello and welcome to the site.

The seventh chapter of tractate Shabbat lists the 39 categories of labor, or "melachos."

Beginning in the very early 20th century, rabbis began looking at electric devices and trying to understand which category (or categories) of prohibited labor they were considered. For an excellent tracing of the issues back to the Talmud, see Rabbis Broyde & Jachter, ["The Use of Electricity on Shabbat and Yom Tov"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ajDZEyuy9V6UJ%3awww.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde_1.htm%20electricity%20on%20shabbos&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com), *Journal of Halacha & Contemporary Society*, No. XXI - Spring 91. The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law) is also very informative.

The same types of actions involved in using a computer to browse the internet are those discussed in the above sources regarding using various other electrical devices, e.g. changing channels on a television set.

Answer (score 6):

I've been interested in this question for a while, especially with recent emergence of ["half shabat"](http://www.thejewishweek.com/news/national/many_orthodox_teens_half_shabbos_way_life) among orthodox teens growing up in a digital world.

There are a number of [reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law), but in my opinion (and, as it turns out Rabbi Auerbach's opinion too) only a couple are good ones. Here are some:

The first issue with using a computer on shabbat is electricity. Even though electricity is not fire, The Chazon Ish forbids it on account of [Building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Building) through completion of a circuit. However, Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (with whom I 100% agree) held that completing a circuit is no more building than closing a door is  (you'd be completing a wall).

The second issue with using a computer on shabbat could be writing. [However](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Computers_and_similar_appliances), due to a computer screen's temporary nature (the image disapears when turned off)  and it's flickering of the image, typing on a screen is not considered writing. It is even permited to erase Hashem's name from a computer screen.

Third, the screen could be considered a [fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Source_of_the_prohibition). This is not the case though since while many hold an incandescent light bulb is fire, that is only because it gives off heat, a fluorescent bulb which doesn't give off heat is not considered fire, and a computer screen would fall under that category.

So, even though electricity is not necessarily assur, and typing on a screen is not considered writing, and a screen is not a fire, I still wouldn't use electricity on shabat for a couple of strong reasons.

First, even though I think it should be allowed to turn on and off non-heat-producing gagets (radio, television, cellphone) I would still prohibit these items on account of using them is not being in the spirit of Shabbat. 
Second, Rabbi Auerbach says it has become a custom not to use electricity on shabbat, and if I were to use electricity I would violate not-breaking a [minhag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Minhag). Additionally, by violating a custom, it would look like I'm not keeping shabbat (marat eyin).

In summation, even though Electricity is probably ok, since it was prohibited it became a custom we can't break. And even though using a computer probably doesn't break any melachos, it's would still be prohibited since it isn't in the spirit of shabbat.

Comment: Again, this addresses using a computer, not viewing the internet.

Comment: Als, regarding writing.  I was under the impression that you can't write even temporarily on shabbat, as a d'rabanan.  For example, playing scrabble is a problem if you use one of those boards that has fixed places for the tiles.  Also, if viewing the internet on a kindle, which uses E-paper, the writing will stay there forever until forced to change.

Comment: The only thing assur about the internet is the content :-p . The real issue with using the internet on shabbat is using the only way we have available to access the internet - a computer. If we could access it directly with our brains, I don't think it would be a violation of shabbat.

Comment: I guess a kindle could be a serious issue, but since on a computer screen the screen is constantly flickering on and off, just too fast for us to see, it it's not even temporary writing. Try to think about it like this - those scrabble letters will stay there forever until you move them, but a web page completely disappears on its own and comes back 24x each second.

Comment: Why don't you think that nolad is an issue?

Comment: does dyeing have the same temporary issue that writing has?  I.e. changing the perceived colors on the screen? I'd be surprised if the gemorah says that temporary dyeing is ok.

Comment: I think molid could be an issue, but not for the reason [Rabbi Yitzchak Schmelkes says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Molid). He holds that generating an electrical current is molid, and I agree with him, but I don't think it applies since I'm not generating any electricity to use my devices at home. If I was off the grid, and I had my own generator to turn on my computer to access the internet, then it may be molid. 

Where I think molid could be a problem is using a computer to create: drawing/painting/photoshop/programming

Comment: I think the problem with Nolad (not molid) a category of muktzeh, because most of the content on the internet did not exist before shabbat, or did not exist in the form you are viewing it.

Comment: I disagree, most internet content exists on the servers unchanged, and is there to be passively viewed. Do you mean, a blog or forum could be muktzeh because its content is updated every day and is therefore guaranteed to be updated on shabbat? I think that's still ok, since it's not muktzeh to read a book which was written on shabat or to look at a painting which was painted on shabbat, especially since in the case of the internet, we can't even call it writing or painting or 'coming into existence'.

Comment: Zaq, you're making some very bold assumptions about the nature of the prohibitions you're speaking about, and there are no primary sources cited dealing with those issues.

Comment: SE says this is too many comments, so I'll ask an official question. But "mail" and "newspapers" are definitely nolad by most authorities and can not be read.  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/would-the-internet-be-considered-muktzeh-due-to-nolad-a-new-thing

Comment: I thought mail and news were prohibited because you may get bad news. I'll look into it.

Comment: Seth, any specifically?

Comment: Re "I disagree, most internet content exists on the servers unchanged, and is there to be passively viewed", which was seemingly in reply to @avi's "most of the content on the internet did not exist before shabbat, or did not exist in the form you are viewing it": AFAICT when you access something online, you're not viewing what's on a server but rather are getting a copy thereof created and delivered to your computer.

Comment: Just by way of example (and I feel this way on virtually all your points, so I'll only use one): "[T]yping on a screen is not considered writing. It is even permited to erase Hashem's name from a computer screen." You don't give any citations for this. Not considered by whom to be writing? Who says it is permitted to erase HaShem's name from a computer screen? Does no one object? This list of opinions is entirely one-sided without any supporting sources.

Comment: It's all pretty much from the same wikipage [Electricity on Shabbat in Jewish law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law) - no raw sources.

as for erasing Hashem's name it's from [Rav Gedalyah Rabinowitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat_in_Jewish_law#Computers_and_similar_appliances) using Halachah Urefu'ah (vol. V)

Comment: [&](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/944731/jewish/Can-I-delete-Gds-name-on-a-computer-screen.htm)

Comment: @zaq Wikipedia's paraphrase of Rav Gedalyah Rabinowitz disagrees explicitly with Rav Moshe's opinion cited in this ask the rabbi write-up. He held that erasure of God's name may only be done by way of _g'rama_ in practicality. But I question the methods of that site's writer anyway because the same Rav Moshe held, based explicitly on the Ta"z, that the literal string "God" has nothing to do with the Name and therefore is not subject to the laws of erasure or the preemptive dashing of a letter.

Comment: Zaq:  The issue of erasing G-d's name on a computer is separate from that of writing on Shabbos.  The poskim hold that you do not erase G-d's name on a computer because, in reality, what is seen on the screen is just a series of 0's and 1's -- in essence, G-d's name was never written, so it can't be erased.  But would you not agree that I can't write a 0 and 1 with a stick in the sand (aside from the issue of plowing) or with a pen on paper on Shabbos?

Comment: The same way that marking a book on shabbat by folding a page a bit (literally, a binary TRUE/FALSE information in a physical manner) it's also ok to have it recorded anywhere, specially when someone understands that by touching any surface on earth he is writing terabytes of random data in the same manner that such data is written in a HD, SSD or LCD screen...

Comment: Not to say that in the same way that water with microscopic "Treif" life forms is allowed since it's not "real" etc then information anywhere in a modern computer is not "real" information. No one can read that without the computer, specially if it's encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that — yes — using the internet on Shabbat is forbidden.

I would base my argument on three reasons:

1. The concept of 'Nolad' (new things which didn't exist before Friday). (90% of what you would be looking at on the internet would have been created that day.)
2. There is a general concept about not doing things which is not in the spirit of shabbat, even if you doesn't violate any actual melacha.  (For example, talking about business on Shabbas.)
3. Looking at the internet potentially violates two melachot.  Writing, and Dyeing.
4. There is a generally accepted practice to refrain from actively interacting with eletrical devices on Shabbat, unless there is a great need for shabbat, and the action which you do is only activated via a grama.  while not violating any specific melacha, this has become the custom of Shabbat-observant Jews worldwide.

I'd appreciate if anyone who knows can help me find sources — i.e. which pages in tractate Shabbat these topics come up.

Comment: -1: The obvious reason not to access the Internet is I think the use of electricity, which you don't address at all. Also, a source for the application to accessing the Internet of the prohibitions on _nolad_, weekday activities, writing, and dyeing would be nice.

Comment: As of yet, 'eletricity' is not one of the 39 melachot, and none of the usual explanations of why eletricity is melecha really applies to modern access of the internet.

Comment: [Gershon Gold's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8972) discusses circuits. I don't know computer science so really can't speak to the topic. See also [Shalom's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8976) and the _J. Hal. Contemp. Soc._ article cited therein, section II.

Comment: J. Hal. Contemp was written in 1991, not very up to date with modern technology.  You can read how various types of keyboards work. Not all create circuits when keys are pressed.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Hall-effect_keyboard

Comment: The asker didn't ask whether it's in violation of _Shabas_ to use the Internet in the specific case that one's using more modern technology, but asked generally. If someone asked whether one's allowed to eat lasagna made of meat and cheese, would you say "The only problem is that it's _bishul akum_", since the asker might have meant the specific case that one's using cheese made of human milk and a label was attached to that effect? [CYLOR.] No, you'd say "it's forbidden" (maybe adding "unless the cheese is made of human milk and..."). Answers deal with general cases.

Comment: I think you fail to appreciate that answers that worked in 1991, no longer apply to "general usage" of technology.  It is predicted that by the end of next year, more people will access the internet through mobile devices than from a PC.  All mobile devices, use non-mechanical keyboards.  Receiving email for example, is more likely to happen on a mobile device than on a "traditional" pc.  Also, most orthodox Jews who access the internet on shabbat, do so from the latest modern technology, as zaq referenced.

Comment: Perhaps I do. And, yes, the (very disturbing, incidentally) _Week_ article zaq cites does imply that.

Answer (score 1):

The possible categories:

A) Lighting a fire: When a switch is turned on, there is a spark. This is similar to striking a match, where a spark is created as a direct result from your action, and it is also the desired result.

B) Adding fuel to a fire: In the case of a standby switch, the electricity is present but in a different channel. When changing from standby to active, it involves a relay switch changing the flow of the current. The opening of the relay for the new channel is similar to throwing wood or other fuel onto a fire.

C) Makeh b'patish — the final hammer blow: By activating the circuit, you effectively perform the final task in order to make the circuit active, the same as putting the finishing touches to an article to make it useable.

D) Boneh — building: By building the circuit and making it active.

E) Every time you hit a key, you complete the circuit temporarily. In addition, using a computer/internet is Uvdei D'chol and should not be done.

Comment: That has nothing to do with watching the internet, and everything to do with turning on a computer.  Also, many computers don't use seperate circuits for everything anymore. (i.e. a touch screen phone)

Comment: @avi - What about _hashma'as kol_? If I am interpreting the question correctly that would seem to be a primary issue as well.

Comment: A. There is no spark when using the internet, assuming the computer is on before shabbat.  B. There is no fire and nothing is burning, so how can you be "Adding fuel"?  C. The internet is usable as is... how can viewing it be makeh b'patish? Maybe if you finished a post, or comment.. but viewing it alone doesn't do that.  D. A computer is not an old fashioned flashlight. All circuits are complete and active.

Comment: @WAF I don't really see how.  I'm currently using the internet with no speakers, on a laptop that is more silent than my refrigerator.

Comment: @avi This will all depend on the use intended by the questioner.

Comment: @avi, actually circuits are composed of 1's and 0's. when you relay something over the web it translate to binary, also all electronic devices use circuits, transistors, capacitors, etc. which control the flow of electricity. A computer or smartphone or any device works by interpreting the on and off pulse of electricity. Thus, using any electric device is creating microscopic sparks, even if it seems continuous. If you shoot a video of a tv screen, you will see lines and notice the picture flickering on and off as well, but it looks continuous when in reality it is not. A battery in laptops w

Comment: Hi Dan! I'm afraid I have to disagree. Just because something releases electricity doesn't mean there are sparks. Sparks are caused by too strong a voltage difference through air, ripping off electrons and breaking into the molecular structure. That doesn't happen "microscopically" in a computer. And in any event, halacha doesn't usually consider things happening microscopically as relevant.

Comment: @Dan There are no "1's and 0's" They don't exist. There is either electricity flowing at one rate, or there is eletricity flowing at another rate, or there is some other method to distinguish between 2 states.  This used to be done by a physical movement in a circuit either being opened or closed. (yes electricity, or no electricity)  That is not how it is done on smarthphones or most computers today.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen opinions that hold that the active use of a computer on Shabbos is prohibited.

Some rabbis will permit leaving a computer on to self-updating news or weather channels under certain circumstances.  According to [Rabbi Chaim Tabasky](http://e.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?cat=527), these conditions include: 
(1) The web site is not Jewish or Israeli (so that you do not gain benefit from the Chilul Shabbat of a Jew) and (2) the computer buttons are covered, or you put on a sign that says Shabbos so you will not come to touch any buttons. He notes that with respect to Israeli news, it may be difficult to guarantee that the camera crew, etc, does not include any Jews. If you are reasonably certain, then you can watch, but I'm not sure if you can ascertain this.  Rabbi Tabasky, however, cautions that this should only be done in circumstances where getting news updates (like during a war) would contribute to peace of mind on Shabbos. Normally, he states "the true Shabbat menucha should come from caring about the situation but allowing Shabbat to go by without involvement in the ongoing news, in order to look at things freshly after Shabbat."

Comment: B&H photo which is owned by Chassidim in NYC runs their website 24/7/365

Comment: @hunterp Welcome back to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around, contribute and enjoy.

Comment: @hunterp, what does that have to do with this?

Comment: @SethJ, it's directly related to the answer's "The web site is not Jewish or Israeli (so that you do not gain benefit from the Chilul Shabbat of a Jew)", which makes it sound like a Jewish-owned site runs only with _chilul Shabas_: B&H is Jewish-owned and runs on _Shabas_ with (presumably) no _chilul Shabas_.

Answer (score -5):

Personally, as long as all other prohibitions on Shabbat are kept, then the use of a computer, and subsequently the internet, would be at *most* a minor transgression.  I rationalise this following the principle that it is permissible to violate a negative Mitzvah so to fulfil a positive one e.g. Shatnez is permissible if it is to tie tzitzit with, thus if using a computer was for the purpose of studying Torah (i.e. NOT facebook!), as perhaps not all of us can afford personal copies for the home of the near endless literature and commentary on the Torah, I would argue that it is excusable.  Additionally, as using a computer is neither for the purpose of lighting nor heating, which are the essential components of fire, I would feel that it is OK (though the screen is lit, and some heat may come from the processor, it is not useable in any practical sense for light and/or heat benefit).  Aside from the issue of fire, all other prohibitions are rabbinical, fire being one of only a few explicit prohibitions on Shabbat given in the Torah (the others being working at occupations/gathering-in of raw materials and cooking - the former directly contributing to the kindling of a fire, and the latter a result of using fire - there is a clear causal link between the three!)

There is a discussion here on the matter of negative/positive Mitzvot [How far may one go with doing an aveira (violating a negative mitzva) if it means performing a positive mitzva?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44051/how-far-may-one-go-with-doing-an-aveira-violating-a-negative-mitzva-if-it-mean/44055)

Comment: There are good and ample reasons we don't rely on our own logic and ideas when deciding _halacha_ unless we've learned a good long time from others first. Note that the permissibility to violate a negative command in order to perform a positive one doesn't apply when the former is working on the sabbath, because working on the sabbath is a violation of a positive command also. Fire is not the only activity banned on the sabbath by divine command, even if it's (possibly) the only one explicitly in the Torah.

Comment: I wish it was like that TBH but it isn't and I say this because today the internet, phone and computer has not only enhanced our ability to work but also has taken over our lives in such a way that it feels like work when ever you are on social media or what ever it is that you occupy (Waste) your time on using such modern devices. You are wrong. I know people who literally feel like using social media is akin to being productive.They make no money. ALSO Shabbat is about getting together and spending time with each other and the phone essentially murders that not only on shabbat but everywhere