# Why can't electricity be manipulated on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, electricity

Why can't we use and change electricity  on Shabbat and YomTov?  By this I mean why can't we turn lights on and off?

I've heard Rabbis say that its because you can't complete a circuit on Shabbat, and that's what you'd be doing by turning the light on and off.  Another time I heard electricity was like fire.

Is this the only reason?  If not, what are the others?

Comment: Have you searched the site? This sounds like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @avi - Oddly enough, I can't find a question on use of electricity in Shabbat that's a general one. Anyone else?

Comment: Take a look at the detailed answer to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/is-using-a-kindle-on-shabbat-permitted

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Certainly, that's a variation of this. That answer goes into detail on the creating of letterforms, but also covers electricity. If this gets closed, so be it, but I think there's no reason not to have variations open. Perhaps, to be a more useful question, this one could focus more on, say, the history of the issue? (The final sentence of this question hints at that in any case.)

Comment: There are several answers that have discussed the issue, but no question that addressed it head on. I'm strongly inclined not to close this, and hope it generates (oy) some good answers.

Comment: @msh210 agreed.  I just remembered so many answers on this topic, I thought the question must have been asked before.

Comment: (In the most respectful tone possible): Can someone please give me an answer already?

Comment: I know this is an unusual source, but it seems someone did a very good job writing it up. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat). But really as far as I can tell electricity has the same rules as magnetism (it's the same force after all): don't do any Melakha with it.

Comment: Not an answer, but noteworthy. The [Sforno in Vayakhel](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=35&mefaresh=sforno) writes that fire is prohibited because of how central it is to any Melacha. Electricity definitely fits the bill. However, obviously we can't Pasken based on reasons we derive.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are nine possible reasons not to use electricity on Shabbat

Opinions about electricity range from deorita, d'rabanan and technially, not really an issur.
The two most commonly cited sources on the topic are the Chazon Ish and R. Auerbach who's opinions on this vary greatly.

### Igniting a fire

The basic example of using electricity, (turning on an incandescent light switch) violates the Torah prohibition of lighting a fire on shabbat. (the metal glows, and gets hot) However, even though this was the first application of electricity, and it's the most common, and clearly not allowed, it is not a catch all reason for all uses of electricity.

### Molid

Many want to say that using electricity creates situations of Molid (creating something new) However, R. Auerbach says that you can't expand Molid beyond its usage as defined by the Talmud.

### Boneh

The Chazon Ish says that closing a circuit to create current falls under the deoraita of Boneh. Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach disagreed in the strongest terms. The reasons for this require an indepth understanding of Boneh.

### Makeh Bapatish

Some try to argue that turning on or off an electrical appliance, or just using a button on it, is the "final step" that finishes the the item. R. Auerbach greatly dissagreed with this.

### Sparks

If the electrical device always and purposefully creates sparks, (like my radiator for example) the creation of sparks might be a problem.

### Additional fuel consumption

In Israel, or places where power plants are run/owned by Jews, the use of electricity might cause these power plants to consume more fuel.

### Heating metal

Electricity entering into a wire might heat that wire (according to the Chazon Ish). However, in recent years the prevalence of solid-state technology has made the reality underlying this concern obsolete in many cases.

### Minhag

Rabbi Auerbach says that outside the case of an incandescent light bulb, the true reason not to use electricity on shabbat/yom tov is minhag.

### Not Shabastik/ In the spirit of Shabbat / yom tov.

Many say that while electricity in most cases might actually be allowed, it's not in the mood of shabbos and is a "davar chol", something that is normally done during the week. Especially after the past 80 years of Jews not using electricity on Shabbat.

Comment: +1 Firstly, thanks for your expansive answer.  

Does this mean that if I use a bulb that doesn't get the slightest bit hot (OK, the slightest bit, but not much more than that) for example a CFL or an LED, would I still be igniting a fire?

Comment: "closing a circuit to create current..." I might be mistaken, however I didn't think that closing a circuit created current.  Furthermore, by connecting two ends of a paperclip together, you'd be "creating a circuit".  Can you please refine your explanation of Boneh?

Comment: I don't understand the boneh argument, for that and many other reasons :) (like the "normal use" clause.

Comment: CFL, actually work by burning a small element.  Any lightbulb that eventually "goes out", must work through some fuel being consumed. In the traditional case, it's the tungsten.

Comment: About the additional fuel consumption... What about if the light or electrical device is solar powered?

Comment: Avi the Rabbis who called incandescent bulbs fire did so because the filament gets red hot and there is a Rambam that calls a red hot metal by the term eish, fire. This is independent of spark theories or other types of fire. Its a focus on the glowing hot metal.

Comment: Where exactly are you quoting the Minhag idea from?

Comment: @user6591, he got it from the following link, I suppose, not sure. http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/broyde_1.htm (search for tradition and not Minhag)

Comment: @avi If one holds by R'Auerbach, could one then use electricity on Shabbos (other than incandescent bulbs) in certain cases of great need? I can imagine an argument for transgressing minhag to avoid great detriment to one's parnassa, for example -- as crazy as that sounds...

Comment: @SAH That is what the Tzomet institute bases their inventions on.

Comment: Not arguing with the answer, but the problem with calling incandescent bulbs "fire" is the fire triangle definition of what is required for fire.  1) Fuel, yes, the filament is fuel, 2) Heat, yes the filament heats up, 3) Oxygen.  There is NO oxygen in incandescent bulbs, they contain an inert gas, usually argon.  So, technically, incandescent bulbs are not fire.

Comment: Heat, fuel, and light is what defines fire. Fuel, heat, and oxygen is what defines combustion. Not always the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Hillel Zacks at a Shuir Pesicha on Maseches Shabbos wanted to prove that it is prohibited as "Meleches Tofer".

- רב הלל בשיעור פתיחה בישיבה למסכת שבת: אמר שגדולי ישראל שבכל הדורות שקדו על תקנת ישראל שלא יעברו איסורים, וכשהתחדש החשמל רצו למנוע את ישראל מלעבור על איסור ולהדליק חשמל בשבת, אבל לא מצאו מדין איזה מלאכה בעצם זה אסור. אז בהתחלה אמרו שזה מבעיר, אח"כ התחדשו הפלורליסטים שזה כבר לא מבעיר ולא ידעו מאיזה דין לאסור, עד שבא החזו"א ואמר שזה משום בונה ואף אחד לא מבין אז אי אפשר להתווכח. היה עוד אחד (י"א שהכוונה על עצמו) אחרי זה שרצה לטעון שזה בכלל תופר... עד כאן דבריו.

Answer (score -3):

One more reason is shvisas keilim which is a gezeira dirabanan from the times of chazzal. And while Beis Hillel allowed one to leave his keili to continue a milacha that was started before shabbos, such as soaking material in dye or leaving a pot of food to continue cooking, as long as the other gezeiros were taken into account, Beus Hillel is in agreement with Beis Shamai that a keili cannot start a milacha on shabos.

This may or may not preclude adjustments of the keili such as dimming a light, but it would definitely apply to turning it on and most other functions of today's electronic devices.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This answer refers to timers, not to electricity. According to this what is wrong with my turning on a fan?

Comment: It also answers any time your fan gets turned on on shabbos. Whether by you or by a timer.

Comment: No it doesn't. What Melacha is my fan doing that Shvisas Keilim applies?