# Why do all people disappear on Saturday at mi.yodeya, is this considered work?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, stackexchange

I understand Saturday is sabath but mi.yodeya is a site for jewish learning and nothing related to work , so why do people disappear from here on Saturdays? Does answering questions or questing etc also considered work?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12572/759

Comment: Using electrical devices is considered work for a variety of reasons, so we do not use computers on Saturdays.

Comment: (Until the end of the Sabbath, of course)

Comment: I considered moving this question to meta but didn't -- while a question about traffic patterns is meta, a question about the *reason* for that isn't.

Comment: Is this not a dupe?

Comment: @SethJ Why would it be? (or am I not seeing the question you refer to as the dupe?)

Comment: @SethJ, the *answer* is the same, but I don't think the *question* is a dupe.

Comment: @double aa elements of the question you linked and his own question ( http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28657/what-is-considered-work-in-sabath)

Comment: @SethJ How is my linked question a dupe? That asks why X, this asks is Y included in Z.

Answer (score 12):

As noted in the comments, using electricity is *melacha* and thus forbidden on Shabbat.  See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12572/472) for more information about why electricity is prohibited.  In addition, writing is forbidden on Shabbat, even if the text is ephemeral.  Since, so far, it is not possible to ask and answer questions on Mi Yodeya without using electricity and writing, the Shabbat-observant participants here do not engage in those activities on Shabbat.  (Or Yom Tov, holidays.)

Shabbat is of course determined by local astronomical events and Mi Yodeya is a worldwide community -- just because it's Shabbat in North America doesn't mean it is in Australia or Israel or Europe, after all.  Further, as noted by Daniel in a comment, this site is also used by non-Jews, who aren't bound by Shabbat restrictions and are welcome to use the site then.  So you will likely see some activity here on Saturday, but less than the rest of the week.

Comment: Also, we (hopefully) appeal to other people besides Jews, and they are are more than welcome to access Mi Yodeya on Shabbat.

Comment: Even with a water operated internet we would still have the issue of writing. While it won't be a biblical prohibition since it is not lasting text, it is still rabbinically prohibited.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Are you sure about that? Even though the letters appearing on the screen has no apparent connection to our pushing water-operated buttons on the keyboard?