# Sending/reading SMS on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, phone

Recently a debate of usage of cellphones on Shabbat has come up, mainly about reading and sending text messages.

I was wondering what the specific reasoning is behind not allowing it on Shabbat.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand. Why _wouldn't_ it be forbidden, just like all other uses of electricity?

Comment: Where did you see such a debate?

Comment: In Israel this debate has opened up over the last few weeks. It seems there are certain circles who want to continue being "religious" but don't feel the need to turn off their cell phones before Shabbat.
They say there is a reasoning behind this, I just can't figure out the (theoretical) reasons.

Comment: @Gidil, So you want to know what the reason for _allowing_ them would be?

Comment: Yes.
I personally don't **need** this but I want to understand the other side of the debate.

Comment: @Gidil Ah. Because you wrote "_what the specific reasoning is behind **not** allowing it_". Would you like to edit that? Also, you may wish to offer more information about this discussion and the people who espouse this view.

Comment: the debate is not about allowing the use of text messages on shabbos halachacly. <br> it is about keeping "half shabbos" and still being considered orthodox.

Comment: Can you perhaps link to some examples of this debate?

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/946296_604204586285792_1313269471_n.jpg

Comment: this is the article http://www.nrg.co.il/online/11/ART2/493/440.html?snopcmdt=1

Comment: and here is rabbi scherlow's  response http://www.nrg.co.il/online/11/ART2/494/391.html?hp=1&cat=1103&loc=13

Comment: The only debate is about electricity being a melacha. Thus it's not about sending text messages at all (typing on a computer isn't seen as "writing" nor is it on any other device). I don't know why Israelis are debating whether or not using a cell phone for texting specifically is a melacha, but this isn't the concern in any mainstream Orthodox circles.

Comment: @HodofHod, everything is permitted unless there's a reason to forbid it. If the asker wants to know reasons to forbid SMSing, I think that's a reasonable question. Otoh, based on the comments above, it seems as though he wants to know reasons to permit it, which doesn't seem like a reasonable question to me unless the question incorporates some reason to forbid SMSing that the asker then wants a _heter_ for.

Comment: @msh210 I don't really think either thing is a reasonable question to ask here. If he is asking for reasons why it is forbidden, he would have to explain why [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12572/1713) doesn't answer it. If he is asking for reasons why it is allowed, then it's not really appropriate based on your reason.

Comment: @msh210 The user's other posts have led me to believe that he knows very well that using electricity on Shabbos is considered forbidden, and that texting would be included in that.

Comment: When purchasing the reissued work on electricity (מאורי אש) by RSZ Auerbach, a new book (קרני אורה) by RZM Koren with modern applications of RSZA's work is included. An entire chapter deals with screens while another deals with computers. I'd argue that the original question is sufficiently unique from the general question of flipping a light switch to deem it a non-duplicate.