# Talking to Alexa on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

What prohibition would talking to a virtual assistant like Alexa, Siri or Google on Shabbos fall under?

"Alexa, turn on the lights"

"Alexa, play Zemiros"

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12572/759

Comment: In this answer it falls under the last two - Minhag and non-Sabbatical behaviour: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12604/15579

Comment: First I was thinking about wiping "turn on the lights" because this is entirely different question, but it seems that that's the only interesting part here - manipulating elactricity with the power of the mind (non-physical interaction).

Comment: ME: "Alexa, turn on the lights." ALEXA: "Did you mean to say -- *Alexa, it's dark in here, hint hint*?"

Comment: @Shalom That's not Alexa. Maybe "Alexandra" or "Sendra", for short ;-)

Comment: Besides the issues mentioned in the answer for @DonielF's link, I think that talking to Alexa might constitute the same issues as activating a microphone / speaker / voice receiver on Shabbat.  Alexa uses the receiver to listen, as well as a mic to talk. (I won't delve into the issues of whether Alexa needs to rest on Shabbat, or not.) You're also intentionally activating that blinking blue light.

Comment: @DanF Why would Alexa have any issues not applicable to Siri?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/888311/rabbi-zvi-sobolofsky/must-alexa-keep-shabbos-hilchos-shabbos-for-the-21st-century/

Comment: @Shalom- that's actually the interesting part of the question