# Tanakh reading on iPad on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, adult-learning, conservative-judaism

As I understand, Modern Orthodox Judaism forbids reading Tanakh from iPad/Kindle on Shabbat.

Does Conservative Judaism allow reading Tanakh/Torah on an iPad during Shabbat?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/is-using-a-non-touch-screen-kindle-on-shabbat-permitted?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Conservative Judaism allow reading Tanakh/Torah on an iPad during Shabbat?

In ["The  Use Of Electrical And Electronic Devices On Shabbat"](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/2020-05/ElectricSabbathSpring2012.pdf) (p.48), [Rabbi Daniel S. Nevins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_S._Nevins) explains:

> Returning to the  subject of  e-readers, as  we  have  seen  above  the use of  these devices  on  Shabbat  is  problematic  on many  levels.  Downloading  new  content  and making notations  are  biblically prohibited  activities  under  the  category of  toledat  koteiv, derivative  forms  of  writing.  Purchasing new  content is  additionally  forbidden  by  the rabbis  under  the  rubric  of  shvut.  Using  e-readers to  display  new screen  views which  are transient in  that they automatically shut off  after  a  few  minutes  of  inactivity would  not be  biblically  prohibited but  would be  banned rabbinically  as  toldat  koteiv  d’rabbanan. However,  if  such  an  e-reader had  its network  functions disabled  and  were used  to  display  text in a  temporary  fashion  (thus reducing  the prohibition  of  writing  to  the rabbinic  level  of  כבוד דרבנן) for  the sake  of  a  visually  disabled  person  who  had  no  other  way  to  read,  we would  override  the rabbinic  level  prohibitions in  deference to  כבוד הבריות, the  demands  of  human  dignity.

The problem that might appear when using a electronic device - a mobile phone, is that when you use it for studying Torah on Shabbos for example, who is to say that you won't use it for "accidentaly" searching something on the web? As explained in this [article](https://thejewishnews.com/2012/07/25/technology-vs-shabbat/):

> Once you’re using your computer and using your TV, then you might use it for other things as well.